# Move, will you?

Tags: c++11

Lets look into this snippet and as expected I get In && printed. However, instead of z = x+y if I had written S z(x + y) I don't get the call to "In move". Instead the temporary created inside operator+ seems to be what z is. Maybe the compiler is optimizing it but I don't quite get it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
  S(int N1) : N(N1) {
    cout << "In orig " << N << "\n";
  }

  S(S& s) {
    N = s.N;
    cout << "In copy\n";
  }

  S(S&& s) {
    N = s.N;
    cout << "In move\n";
  }

  S const & operator=(S&& s) {
    cout << "In &&\n";
  }

  S operator+(S const & s) {
    cout << "In +\n";
    return S(N + s.N);
  }

  int N;
};

int main()
{
  S x(33), y(44);
  S z = 99; // instead of this line and next try S z(x + y); --> no move constructor??
  z = (x + y);
}
```

Comment: I am using clang++ 3.1

Comment: optimization right? why force it?

Comment: @Fanatic23: it's officially authorized by the standard, and apparently both very cheap to implement and very good for performance, so at least GCC and clang implement it even with no optimization settings. Use `-fno-elide-constructors` to get rid of copy elision (and get rid of a lot of performance too)

Comment: @Mat that worked, u rock